# Get Content Folder Images In Areas Admin View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want To get Images in Project/Areas/Admin/Index ..
and images in Project/Content Folder
so it show error when i use

```
            <img src="@item.ProductImagePath" />
```

error
*GET https://localhost:44378/Admin/Home/Content/dress3.jpg ERROR..*
it find image on Admin but images are in content folder
It Added Admin in Image Path

[here the image of directory and img tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG6CC.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include text code instead of a picture of code.

Comment: `ProductImagePath` is obviously wrong, fix whatever is generating that value.

Answer (score -1):

I think you use wrong routes.
for example, this image in admin areas and you can see it:
https://take-car.ru/areas/admin/MxPBksiUmnA.jpg